# After Insert - Update Lookup on Custom object with other field

Tags: trigger, field-update, insert

After performing a bulk upload, I need to update the Lookup on custom object. Matching field exists on the parent as external ID but that may add complexity.

```
if field Custom.loc__c = DAV then update Custom.Lookup__c = Davis
```

Other values :

```
DAV Davis
EUC Euclid
WOL Wolf
```

Thanks, I'm not too familiar with APEX but know this can't be done with WF.

Comment: just the 3 values or are there more? If not, do we expect these to be more in future?

Comment: There is a finite list of values about 15. Values are on same object will be bulk uploaded in when rest of data is created new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details might be required to address this completely, also its important to understand what you tried. Just to give you a jump start - Below apex code might work by replacing 'custom' with your object names and 'lookup__c' with field name and object name respectively.

```
trigger customTrigger on custom (before insert){
    Set<String> nameString = new Set<String>{'Davis','Euclid','Wolf'};
    Map<String,Lookup__c> keyByLookupMap = new Map<String,Lookup__c>();
    for(Lookup__c lc : [Select Id, Name from Lookup__c where Name IN : nameString]){
        keyByLookupMap.put(lc.name,lc);
    }
    for(custom obj : trigger.new){
        if(obj.loc__c == 'DAV'){
            if(keyByLookupMap.containsKey('Davis'))
            obj.lookup__c = keyByLookupMap.get('Davis');
        }
        if(obj.loc__c == 'EUC'){
            if(keyByLookupMap.containsKey('Euclid'))
            obj.lookup__c = keyByLookupMap.get('Davis');
        }
        if(obj.loc__c == 'WOL'){
            if(keyByLookupMap.containsKey('Wolf'))
            obj.lookup__c = keyByLookupMap.get('Davis');
        }
    }
}
```

However its important to understand how loc__c is evaluated and can we have more values in future for Names.